# OCHamcrest matcher parameter is incompatible with Mockito mock at Verify

Tags: objective-c, ocmockito, ochamcrest

with the following unit test I'm using Mockito to mock NSUserDefaults but when I try to verify using OCHamcrest matcher to test that the param is an instance of an NSDictionary I get the warning:

> Sending 'id{HCMatcher}' to parameter of incompatible type
>   'NSDictionary *'

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaultsMock = mockClass([NSUserDefaults class]); 
//OR -- NSUserDefaults *userDefaultsMock = mock([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]class]);

Engineer *sut = [[Engineer alloc]init];

[given([userDefaultsMock stringForKey:@"engineerId"]) willReturn:@"02345"];

BOOL result = [sut setCurrentEngineerId:@"02345" userDefaults:userDefaultsMock];
[verify(userDefaultsMock) registerDefaults:instanceOf([NSDictionary class])];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says, "Typed arguments will issue a warning that the matcher is the wrong type. Just cast the matcher to id."

In your case,

```
[verify(userDefaultsMock) registerDefaults:(id)instanceOf([NSDictionary class])];
```

Comment: Thanks - didn't spot that.